# what is the purpose of /private/var/db/crls folder

Tags: macos, filesystem

What is the purpose of `/private/var/db/crls` folder on a mac? I noticed that it gets updated regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's system-wide cache of Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs).
I think Safari puts its cache there, that's why you see it's being updated.